# Detect frame and split to 78x42 areas and give average color of each area

Tags: python, opencv

for my home project I want to create some kind of ambilight. The backlighting already works by me passing a photo into a Python program and putting the photo into a 78x42 grid and then sending each edge color to an LED light. The LEDs are located behind the TV to create a background glow.

For now, the effect is already very nice.

Now the next step:

A Raspberry-Pi with a connected RPI camera should be pointed at the TV and the edge colors should be determined and sent to the LEDs.

So that the program learns where the TV is, I have already written a program, which first creates 4 images (all white, all red, all green and all blue), sends these images to the Chromecast and displays them. From each picture a photo is made. So I have 4 photos on which the TV can be seen. Each time the TV shows only one color.

I made the pictures in red, green and blue to get a color correction later, or to calibrate the colors. But that's not what I want to talk about here.

First I want to recognize the TV. I have no experience with OpenCV. I already have the following script, but I can't get any further from here.

```
import skimage
import skimage.feature
import skimage.viewer
import matplotlib
import cv2

image = skimage.io.imread(fname='tvImageW.jpg', as_gray=True)

edges = skimage.feature.canny(
    image=image,
    sigma=1,
    low_threshold=0.1,
    high_threshold=1.2,
)

matplotlib.image.imsave('edges.png', edges)
```

[Original Image of TV with plain white content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR92E.jpg)

[Result of the python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikzu8.png)

Does anyone have an idea or a plan how I can proceed?

I am convinced that it would be relatively easy to implement with OpenCV, if you knew your way around...

THANKS for every hint.

---

With Mario's help, I am now at the point of finding the contour. I have also discovered how to figure out the 4 corners of the TV. Here is my code so far:

```
import cv2
from math import sqrt

im = cv2.imread('tvImageW.jpg')
edges = cv2.Canny(im, 100, 200)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, 
        cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

     # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

# find the perimeter of the contour
perim = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
# setting the precision
epsilon = 0.02*perim
# approximating the contour with a polygon
approxCorners = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)

cv2.drawContours(im, [c], 0, (255,255,0), 2)
cv2.drawContours(im, approxCorners, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

Now I have 3 ideas that I will test further:

1. divide the lines between the points into 78 (or 42) parts. Then examine the individual grids for the color average.
2. use the 4 corner-points and the following guide to bring the image into the right perspective and then use my (already existing) routine: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/
3. create a new test image and there mark the areas I am interested in and again recognize these contours. Each detected contour within the TV contour would then be a LED pixel at the end.

I suspect that point 2 is too slow at run time. Therefore I will start with the first point. Here, however, there could be problems with the perspective. If the problems are acceptable, I have the result. If it is not acceptable, I will try point 3....

---

### Here is an attempt to represent the problem graphically. Below the trapezoid of the TV (tv-contour). Above the corrected image of the TV with the areas I am interested in.
[image: Here is an attempt to represent the problem graphically. Below the trapezoid of the TV (tv-contour). Above the corrected image of the TV with the areas I am interested in.]

Here is an image of the TV displaying the 78x42 grid:
[image]

Comment: i have post the code for recognize the Tv . Now we have the borders points of Tv .  What next step ?

Comment: Why not the avg color of entire screen without fields/cells  78 or 42 parts , and without warp affine transformations ?      How many leds you have ?

Comment: There are 240 leds: top and bottom 78, right and left 42

Comment: if you show the grid you need in your  tv,  in reality,  then you can get all coord of the grid,  one time ,  with no efforts ,   extremely lite and fast at runtime.  One time as reference and then use this grid reference to get avg colors of each single cell .

Comment: Yes. I need the grid inside the tv-contour. Not inside your (green) rectagle. Then only inspect the outer 236 cells (240 - the 4 corners, there are always two leds).

Comment: ok , now it 's clear.  Please give me the dimension of you screen in real world , not in pixel but in cm if you can.

Comment: I have included the attempt to show the problem graphically above. Now noticed that the trapezoid is the wrong way around. But the problem should still be clear.

Comment: The dimension of the TV is 130cm x 70cm

Comment: ok , perfect.  i have included a grid 78x42 parts based on your tv screen dimension 130x700 cm . Please  show this grid image in your wall tv  and include a pic .  I would try to get a grid reference from this  new tv picture.

Comment: the affine warp approach is interesting but we still need to be able to see the colors from that angle. In the meantime I can try to get the coordinates of the grid projected on the TV as a reference, and if it works it will be faster than warp affine transformation running in your RaspB

Comment: I have edited the answer and assempled  and correct the pyimagesearch scripts with our main script.  Take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that tv is the max area contour.
In the dark you need different parameters

create a folder and name it "pyimagesearch".
Behind this folder we will put the  empty `__init__.py` file and  `transform.py` file that contains the functions to warp the image.

***This is our main file:***

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyimagesearch.transform import *

im=cv2.imread('images/tv-wall.jpg')

img = im.copy()
edges = cv2.dilate(cv2.Canny(im,1,100),(2,2) ,iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, 
        cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# find the biggest countour (c) by the area
c  = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (255,255,0), 2)

# find the perimeter of the contour
perim = cv2.arcLength(c, True)

# setting the precision
epsilon = 0.02*perim

# approximating the contour with a polygon
approxCorners = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)

#draw 4 yellow corners points 
for p in approxCorners:
    cv2.circle(img,(p[0],p[1]),3,(0,255,255),3)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

Now we use 'approxCorners' to warp the 'im' image
with corrected functions from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/

```
pts = np.array( approxCorners  , dtype = "float32")

warped = four_point_transform(im, pts)


#Your tv w/h  ratio 
ratio=130/70

wrp_h, wrp_w ,depth = warped.shape
rsz_h = int(wrp_h * ratio)

#warped image stretch resize and show
rwarped = cv2.resize(warped,(wrp_w,rsz_h))
cv2.imshow("Warped",rwarped)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Folder structure:**

```
pyimagesearch/__init__.py
pyimagesearch/transform.py
```

This is the **'transform.py'** file  behind  'pyimagesearch' folder

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#This function is different from the original at pyimagesearch
def order_points(pts):

    spts=sorted(pts,key=lambda k:[k[1],k[0]])    
    return np.array( [ 
        tuple(spts[0]),#0 ok
        tuple(spts[1]),#1 ok
        tuple(spts[3]),#3 ok
        tuple(spts[2]) #2 ok
        ])

def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    print("ptsorderd rect",rect)
    print("rect type", type(rect))
    print("rect shape", rect.shape)
    
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect
    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))
    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
            [0, 0],
            [maxWidth - 1, 0],
            [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
            [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
    # return the warped image
    return warped
```

[image: at night you need different parameter]

Comment: Thank you. So now I have found the frame. How do I proceed further. I would have to divide the contour into 78 by 42 fields and then examine each of the fields at the edges to determine the average color....

Comment: What you need can be done in serveral ways . For better clarity can you add a draw/paint image of the result you want ?

Comment: Many thanks. I have brought my original post up to date.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to post my final result here. The script creates a JSON at the end, in which a pixel area is stored for each individual LED. This pixel area is then used by the main program.

All in all it runs very smooth. Surprisingly good even.

In the main program, a higher speed could possibly lead to an (even) better experience, but it's already running better than I would have expected.

If there is a wish, I will post the complete source code on Github:

- Script that sends the images to the TV via Chromecast.
- Script that detects the TV and saves the result of the interesting pixels into a JSON file for the main program.
- Main script that uses the RPI camera, detects the colors and sends them to a NodeMCU.
- Arduino code of the NodeMCU with which transmits the colors to a tethered, 4 meter long, WS2812B behind the TV.

detectTv.py

```
import constant
import detectTvHelper as helper
import cv2
import numpy as np
import json

im = cv2.imread('tvImageW.jpg')
edges = cv2.dilate(cv2.Canny(im,1,100),(2,2) ,iterations=1) #cv2.Canny(im, 100, 200)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# find the biggest countour (c) by the area
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

# find the perimeter of the contour
perim = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
# setting the precision
epsilon = 0.02*perim
# approximating the contour with a polygon
approxCorners = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)

cv2.drawContours(im, [c], 0, (255,255,0), 2)
cv2.drawContours(im, approxCorners, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', im)

orderedPoints = helper.order_points(approxCorners)

points =  helper.getPointsBetweenPoints(orderedPoints[0][0], orderedPoints[0][1], orderedPoints[1][0], orderedPoints[1][1], 78)
points += helper.getPointsBetweenPoints(orderedPoints[1][0], orderedPoints[1][1], orderedPoints[2][0], orderedPoints[2][1], 42)    
points += helper.getPointsBetweenPoints(orderedPoints[2][0], orderedPoints[2][1], orderedPoints[3][0], orderedPoints[3][1], 78)
points += helper.getPointsBetweenPoints(orderedPoints[3][0], orderedPoints[3][1], orderedPoints[0][0], orderedPoints[0][1], 42)

result={}

cimg = np.zeros_like(im)
cv2.fillPoly(cimg, pts =[c], color=255)

cBRx,cBRy,cBRw,cBRh = cv2.boundingRect(c)
pts = helper.getMarkedCoordinates(cimg, cBRx, cBRy, cBRw, cBRh)

led = 0
for p in points:
    cimg2 = np.zeros_like(im)
    cv2.circle(cimg2, (p[0], p[1]), radius=constant.COLOR_RADIUS, color=255, thickness=-1)
    pts2 = helper.getMarkedCoordinates(cimg2, p[0]-5, p[1]-5, 10, 10)
    inters = helper.intersect(pts, pts2)
    result[led] = inters
    print(led, len(inters))
    led += 1

with open('pixels.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(result, f)
```

detectTvHelper.py

```
#order corners tl, tr, bl, br
def order_points(approxCorners):
    pts = [
        [approxCorners[0][0][0], approxCorners[0][0][1]], 
        [approxCorners[1][0][0], approxCorners[1][0][1]],
        [approxCorners[2][0][0], approxCorners[2][0][1]], 
        [approxCorners[3][0][0], approxCorners[3][0][1]]]
    rect = [[0, 0]] * 4
    pts.sort()
    if (pts[0][1] < pts[1][1]):
        rect[0] = pts[0]
        rect[3] = pts[1]
    else:
        rect[0] = pts[1]
        rect[3] = pts[0]
    if (pts[2][1] < pts[3][1]):
        rect[1] = pts[2]
        rect[2] = pts[3]
    else:
        rect[1] = pts[3]
        rect[2] = pts[2]
    
    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect

def getPointsBetweenPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2, points):
    res=[]
    for i in range(points):
        newX = x1 + ((x2 - x1) / (points) * (i + 0.5))
        newY = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / (points) * (i + 0.5))
        res.append([round(newX), round(newY)])
    return res


def getMarkedCoordinates(image, x, y, w, h):
    res = []
    for _x in range(x, x + w):
        for _y in range(y, y + h):
            pixel = image[_y][_x]
            if (pixel.max() > 0):
                res.append([_x, _y])
    return res


def intersect(pixels1, pixels2):
    res = []
    m = {}
    if len(pixels1)<len(pixels2):
        pixels1,pixels2 = pixels2,pixels1
    for i in pixels1:
        m[i[0]*1000+i[1]] = True
    for i in pixels2:
        if i[0]*1000+i[1] in m:
            res.append(i)
    return res
```

Since I have only roundimentary Python knowledge, I can imagine that there is room for improvement in one or the other place. I am open for hints.

However, performance does not play the biggest role here. In the main program, every bit of performance counts.